# Draw CGPath As Path is Constructed

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgpath

Is it possible to draw a CGPath as it is created(as each line is added) rather than the entire path of points drawn in an instant? I would like to see the path being drawn as the lines are added to it.

Also, Is it possible to draw a single line at a time as part of the larger path, not drawing the path over itself each time with one extra line?

Answer (score 4):

If you use a CAShapeLayer and set the path as its path property, you can animated the strokeEnd value.

I don't know how simple it would be to add to this dynamically, but I have used this before to animate lines with timing points along the way (but the entire paths of those lines were known in advance)

Answer (score 3):

@wattson12 is absolutely right. Here's an example of how I've done it in the past:

```
- (void)animateBezier
{
    CAShapeLayer *bezier = nil;
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [self bezierPath]; // clearly, generate your path anyway you want

    bezier = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

    bezier.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    bezier.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    bezier.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    bezier.lineWidth   = 5.0;
    bezier.strokeStart = 0.0;
    bezier.strokeEnd   = 1.0;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:bezier];

    CABasicAnimation *animateStrokeEnd = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    animateStrokeEnd.duration  = 1.0;
    animateStrokeEnd.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    animateStrokeEnd.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    [bezier addAnimation:animateStrokeEnd forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
}
```

I don't know if this is what you want, or whether you also want to later animate the addition of an additional point in the path. If this is what you want, you could probably do something where you tweak the fromValue accordingly, or animating the drawing of another segment as a separate path.